# Which will be best deep learning model for topic classification using NLP

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, multiclass-classification, bert

I have a dataset consisting of two columns [Text, topic_labels].
Topic_labels are of 6 categories for ex: [plants,animals,birds,insects etc]

I would like to build deep learning-based models in order to be able to classify topic_labels.
so far I have implemented both supervised[SVM, Logistic] & unsupervised [topic-LDA, Guided-LDA] approaches in a traditional way by applying both Word2Vec & TF-IDF  but I wanted to implement state-of-the-art deep learning classification techniques for the text data?

Suggest me the best deep learning model for text topic classification.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I don't see why you tried unsupervised methods, at first sight if there are 6 specific labels it's standard text classfication, not topic modeling. Also LDA-like methods work just with word, they don't need Wod2Vec or TFIDF. It might be a good idea to focus more on one specific idea or two, instead of trying many things a bit randomly.

Comment: @Erwan, Thanks for your swift response. well as of now am receiving data with labels to train the model but for test or validation data there won't be any shared labeled data & moreover, text data is completely unstructured for that reason I tried unsupervised & rule-based as a combination

Comment: If the goal is text classification, the task should be evaluated with supervised measures. The standard way would be to split your labelled data in order to obtain a labelled test set. Any unlabelled data received later is just "production data", at this stage the performance of the classifier is known and if the data is reasonably similar to the test data then the performance is supposed to be identical. The fact that text is unstructured is not related to the task, actually any text classification task is supposed to work from unstructured text.

Comment: Have a look at Keras https://keras.io/examples/nlp/

Comment: @Erwan for your valuable inputs

Comment: @Peter sure will look into it